# Why won't WPF databindings show text when ToString() has a collaborating object?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, tostring

In a simple form, I bind to a number of different objects -- some go in listboxes; some in textblocks.

A couple of these objects have collaborating objects upon which the `ToString()` method calls when doing its work -- typically a formatter of some kind.

When I step through the code I see that when the databinding is being set up,

1. `ToString()` is called
2. the collaborating object is not `null` and returns the expected result
3. when inspected in the debugger, the objects return the expected result from `ToString()`

**BUT** the text does *not* show up in the form.

The only common thread I see is that these use a collaborating object, whereas the other bindings that show up as expected simply work from properties and methods of the containing object.

If this is confusing, here is the gist in code:

```
public class ThisThingWorks
{
    private SomeObject some_object;

    public ThisThingWorks(SomeObject s) { some_object = s; }

    public override string ToString() { return some_object.name; }
}

public class ThisDoesntWork
{
    private Formatter formatter;
    private SomeObject some_object;

    public ThisDoesntWork(SomeObject o, Formatter f) 
    {
        formatter = f; 
        some_object = o;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return formatter.Format(some_object.name);
    }
}
```

Again, let me reiterate -- the `ToString()` method *works* in every other context -- but when I bind to the object in WPF and expect it to display the result of `ToString()`, I get nothing.

#### Update:

The issue seems to be what I see as a buggy behaviour in the `TextBlock` binding. If I bind the `Text` property to a property of the `DataContext` that is declared as an interface type, `ToString()` is never called. If I change the property declaration to an implementation of the interface, it works as expected. Other controls, like `Label` work fine when binding the `Content` property to a `DataContext` property declared as either the implementation or the interface.

Because this is so far removed from the title and content of this question, I've created a new question here: [WPF binding behaviour different when bound property is declared as interface vs class type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917878/why-doesnt-textblock-databinding-call-tostring-on-a-property-whose-compile-tim)

changed the title: [WPF binding behaviour different when bound property is declared as interface vs class type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917878/wpf-binding-behaviour-different-when-bound-property-is-declared-as-interface-vs-c)

Comment: I don't mean to mention something that is obvious, but ToString() is being called as a fall-back case. Usually you would bind to a property of an object e.g. the source of the binding would be a SomeObject and the display member would be "name".

Comment: This makes no sense. ThisDoesntWork does work. The "collaborating" object is not the cause for what you are seeing.

Comment: @bitbonk Yes, I'm increasingly returning to my initial suspicion that I'm a fool -- but haven't found the root of my foolishness quite yet… I'll update when I do.

Comment: @bitbonk You are right that the collaborator is not to blame -- still not sure what is, though. See my update with link to find steps to reproduce. Thanks.

Comment: @chibacity In this case, the properties are things like `EmailAddress`, `PhoneNumber`, where they exist to hide my implementation of these values, but they behave just like strings when I pass them around or bind to them in the UI. Anyway, I posted an update with a link to more details on how to reproduce the behaviour I'm seeing. Thanks.

Comment: I see what you are driving at but this is not the WPF way, what you are doing is a little, shall we say, unusual. You are relying on some fall-back behaviour which is not meant to be used as a feature i.e. relying on ToString(). I am answering your other question as we speak...

Answer (score 0):

Try these simple changes:

First test your program with this version of the method:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return "This method's really being called."
}
```

If that actually displays something in the UI, now try this version:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    Console.WriteLine(
       string.Format("some_object.name = {0}, formatter.Format(some_object.name) = {1}",
          some_object.name,
          formatter.Format(some_object.name));
    return formatter.Format(some_object.name);
}
```

If this doesn't lead you to figure out what's really wrong, I'll be extremely surprised.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I went down this route before, but wasn't able to track down the issue. As it turns out, the behaviour is different depending on whether the property to which I am binding is declared with an interface type or a class type. I updated the question with a link to steps to reproduce the behaviour.