# WPF binding behaviour different when bound property is declared as interface vs class type?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, xaml

This started with weird behaviour that I thought was tied to my implementation of `ToString()`, and I asked this question: [Why won't WPF databindings show text when ToString() has a collaborating object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916068/why-wont-wpf-databindings-show-text-when-tostring-has-a-collaborating-object)

It turns out to have nothing to do with collaborators and is reproducible.

When I bind `Label.Content` to a property of the `DataContext` that is declared as an interface type, `ToString()` is called on the runtime object and the label displays the result.

When I bind `TextBlock.Text` to the same property, `ToString()` is never called and nothing is displayed. **But**, if I change the declared property to a concrete implementation of the interface, it works as expected.

Is this somehow by design? If so, any idea why?

To reproduce:

- Create a new WPF Application (.NET 3.5 SP1)
- Add the following classes:

> ```
> public interface IFoo
> {
>     string foo_part1 { get; set; }
>     string foo_part2 { get; set; }
> }
>
> public class Foo : IFoo
> {
>     public string foo_part1 { get; set; }
>
>     public string foo_part2 { get; set; }
>
>     public override string ToString() 
>     { 
>         return foo_part1 + " - " + foo_part2; 
>     }
> }
> ```

```
public class Bar
{
    public IFoo foo 
    { 
        get { return new Foo {foo_part1 = "first", foo_part2 = "second"}; } 
    }
}
```

- Set the XAML of Window1 to:

  ```
  <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
       <StackPanel>
          <Label Content="{Binding foo, Mode=Default}"/>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding foo, Mode=Default}"/>
      </StackPanel>
  </Window>
  ```
- in Window1.xaml.cs:

> ```
> public partial class Window1 : Window  
> {  
>     public Window1()  
>     {  
>         InitializeComponent();  
>         DataContext = new Bar();  
>     }  
> }
> ```

When you run this application, you'll see the text only once (at the top, in the label). If you change the type of `foo` property on `Bar` class to `Foo` (instead of `IFoo`) and run the application again, you'll see the text in both controls.

Answer (score 8):

I know this thread is old but I found a workaround for this problem. Use the StringFormat property on the binding:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
     <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="{Binding foo, Mode=Default}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding foo, Mode=Default, StringFormat={}{0}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Henrik, [someone else has asked a very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309863/binding-to-interface-typed-properties), and when I linked them to this one, they said your answer solved their problem. That question is yours to answer if you like; I don't want to take credit when all I did was find a similar question :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you are right. Obviously the `ContentControl.Content` property is implemented differently from the `TextBlock.Text` property. One obvious difference of course is that the `ContentControl` will actually generate a `TextBlock` instance for a content object that is not a `Visual` and doesn't have a `DataTemplate`. The `TextBlock` does not. It will render the text by itself. In both cases the string is determined by

1. the `IValueConverter` (if present in the binding)
2. the `TypeConverter` (if declared)
3. `object.ToString()`

It seems that this algorithm differs only in step 3 between `TextBlock` and `ContentControl` as you have shown. While the `ContentControl` actually resolves the object behind the interface, the `TextBlock` does not. Interesting.

I guess this is something that you have to live with. You have several options now:

- Expose a string property on your interface and bind to that
- Expose the data object as a concrete class instead as an interface
- Use a `ContentControl` instead of a `TextBlock`
- provide a `IValueConverter` and use it in the binding
- provide a `TypeConverter` for your interface
- do something else (there's probably more)