# Binding to interface typed properties

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-4.0

I just got bit by yet another binding oddity in WPF.  Consider the following class and its `IStupid` typed property called `MyStupid`:

```
public struct DumbClass
{
    public IStupid MyStupid { get { return new IsStupid(); } }
}
public interface IStupid{}
public class IsStupid : IStupid{}
```

Now consider the following binding to a `ListBox`:

```
var items = new List<DumbClass>(new []{new DumbClass(), new DumbClass(), new DumbClass()});
OptListBox.ItemsSource = items;
```

There is nothing special about the xaml:

```
<ListBox Name="OptOccurances" Height="238" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,34,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="229" >
</ListBox>
```

As expected, the output of the listbox is 3 rows of "MyProject.DumbClass".

However if I set `DisplayMemberPath="MyStupid"` (or create an ItemTemplate, binding 'MyStupid' directly to a TextBlock in the template), I get 3 empty rows instead, when I expected it to say `MyProject.IsStupid`.  Why is the databinding engine unable to call the default `ToString()` implementation and display the class name.  Is there a workaround for a interface typed property?  At the very least, is there a reason why no binding error is thrown?

Comment: +1 for something else than foo / bar.

Comment: A struct named `DumbClass` is truly dumb because it doesn't even realize that it's not a class.

Comment: binding errors are never "thrown."  You can see any binding errors in the output window of visual studio, do you have any?

Comment: @dan - yeah, changing to struct was one of many things I tried to reproduce the issue.  I just forgot to change it back.

Comment: @Tejas - yes I have looked at the output window (thrown was a bad choice of words on my part).  Even with the verbosity level set to "informative", no information is displayed.

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917878/wpf-binding-behaviour-different-when-bound-property-is-declared-as-interface-vs) with a possible workaround but no definitive resolution.

Comment: @shambulator - the answer you linked actually is fairly definitive - stringformat does fix the issue.  Would you like to post as an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: @b_levitt I've left a comment on the answer that solved it for you; would rather see the person who actually had the WPF knowledge you needed get the credit for the answer!

Comment: Well I would have done both but I did +1 that answer.  To be clear, in the case of my codebehind (vs markup), I used OptListBox.ItemStringFormat = "{0}";

Answer (score 3):

I can reproduce this issue. It looks like WPF bug.

Here is the workaround you can use:
Instead of DisplayMemberPath, you can use Item's DataTemplate with StringFormat parameter, which will forcefully convert property value to string:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="OptOccurances" Height="238" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,34,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="229" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyStupid, StringFormat='{}{0}' }"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Generally you can use WPF Trace Settings to figure out such kind of problems:
[image]

But in this case as I see no binding errors happen.

Additionally you can use WPF Visualizer for Visual Studio 2012, which allows you to investigate tree right from the debug Watch:
[image]

Using the following code you can get TextBlock with its binding:

```
    private void btn_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var listBoxItem = OptOccurances.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as ListBoxItem;
        var item = OptOccurances.Items[1] as DumbClass;
        var tbk =  VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(listBoxItem, 0),0),0) as TextBlock;
        var binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(tbk, TextBlock.TextProperty);
        var be = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(tbk, TextBlock.TextProperty);
        var vs = DependencyPropertyHelper.GetValueSource(tbk, TextBlock.TextProperty);
        var val = tbk.GetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty);
    }
```

And it shows that Binding status is actually active and the object mapped is correct. Obviously internals of Binding (PropertyPathWorker) works differently for getting the value in case type of property

Comment: Even with the trace settings set to verbose, there is no additional information.  No, struct is not the problem - it does the same thing as a class.  No, a string type property works fine.  Even a property of type IsStupid works fine (as opposed to IStupid).  It is the interface type that seems to be the problem

Comment: just noticed that in comments to the question they already referenced this workaround